# Ubuntu 18.04 uses too much RAM

Tags: 18.04, ram-usage

The command `top` in Ubuntu 18.04 shows that 4GB RAM is being used even if I don't run anyhing.

Results of `top`:

[image: Screenshot of 'top']

Results of `free -hm`:

[image: Screenshot of 'free -hm']

PC information:

[image: PC information]

Comment: What does `free -hm` show?  Typically I don't trust `top`'s values to be entirely accurate.  Also, some applications consume far more RAM than normal.  Also "high RAM usage" is entirely subjective and dependent on your system's RAM allocations and applications you use, so we need more detail about your computer and what programs you are running right now.

Comment: @ThomasWard I edited the post, i don't know if that helps. Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: If you run `sudo inxi -t m10` it will show you the top 10 memory using applications and what they are using.  You can also do `sudo inxi -t m20` to show you 20 applications, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the "missing" memory is being used for kernel buffers and (mostly!) the VM / file system page cache.

This is a good thing.  It is making your file system access faster.

---

According to the output from `free` you have:

```
Total: 7.0G
used: 3.9G
free: 1.2G
shared: 11m
buf/cache: 1.9G
available: 2.9G
```

The manual entry for `free` explains these columns as follows:

```
   total  Total installed memory (MemTotal and  SwapTotal  in  /proc/mem‐
          info)

   used   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)

   free   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)

   shared Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo)

   buffers
          Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)

   cache  Memory  used  by  the  page  cache  and  slabs (Cached and SRe‐
          claimable in /proc/meminfo)

   buff/cache
          Sum of buffers and cache

   available
          Estimation of how much memory is  available  for  starting  new
          applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the
          cache or free fields, this field takes into account page  cache
          and  also  that  not  all  reclaimable  memory  slabs  will  be
          reclaimed due to items being in use (MemAvailable in /proc/mem‐
          info,  available  on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+,
          otherwise the same as free)
```

While the kernel buffers are probably not easily reclaimable, the kernel will happily free up the page cache and give the memory to applications ... if there is actual demand for it.  And clearly there isn't a demand at the moment.

In summary, `free` says that there is 2.9G available for instant use, and a further 1.9G ... most of which can be freed up at a moments notice.